# How is resumption from await implemented?

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

I've been reading Eric Lippert's blog posts on Asynchrony in C# 5 ([part 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/11/04/asynchrony-in-c-5-0-part-four-it-s-not-magic.aspx) being particular relevant) and have watched Anders PDC10 talk on the subject and I'm unclear on how continuations from asynchronous methods are resumed in a single threaded context.

Both sources discuss using asynchronous methods in a single threaded UI loop to improve responsiveness and in Anders' example he mentions that when an asynchronous task completes it's continuation is scheduled by the addition of a message to the message pump.

Does the asynchronous method really know that it needs to perform what seems like a context specific action, or was this a simplification?

More generally, how can resumption from asynchronous methods handled in a single threaded context? Is there a requirement for scheduling within a single thread?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The task continuation knows where the continuation needs to be scheduled - e.g. "any thread pool thread" or "the UI thread".

This behaviour is determined by the "awaiter", however - it's not actually part of what the C# compiler is responsible for. The compiler just calls `BeginAwait` and passes in the continuation; the awaiter returns a Boolean value indicating whether the task has already completed synchronously, or whether the caller should return and let the continuation occur asynchronously.

So for the moment, that decision is made in the awaiter returned by `TaskEx` - but I wouldn't be surprised to see it all get bundled into `Task` eventually. That can flow things like the synchronization context, which knows how further actions should be handled.

I'm not quite sure what sort of *genuinely* single-threaded context you're considering... or are you thinking of a situation where the bulk of the work needs to happen in a single thread, but other threads can be involved for the asynchronous bit (e.g. when an HTTP packet is received, processed on an IO completion port thread, and the response *handled* back on the UI thread)?

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer Jon. That was indeed the situation I was thinking of. So am I reading you correctly in thinking that there is some concept of a synchronization context that defines the rescheduling method of the continuation? I think I may need to do some more reading on C# threading!

Comment: @Simon: Yes, there is. I can't remember the details offhand - but look at things like TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext.

Comment: Great, many thanks. I'm unable to upvote your answer yet I'm afraid, I'll rectify this when I have sufficient rep!

Answer (score 7):

Jon's answer is of course great; I thought I'd just add one more thing.

Consider a WinForms application with a single button on a form that runs code when you click the button.

What happens when you are *not* clicking the button?  Nothing. The process exists, the code is running, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. In fact what it is doing is processing messages on the UI thread and determining that none of them are interesting, but it doesn't look like it is doing anything interesting.

When you click the button, suddenly one of those messages is interesting, and the message pump knows that when it sees that click event, it should run some code. So it does.

The asynchrony-on-a-single-thread scenario is just the same. The continuation -- the "what to do after the task is finished" code is effectively an "event handler" of the "task is finished" event. When the task finishes, it "pushes the button" and enqueues a message on the message queue of the UI thread. It doesn't matter whether it does so from the UI thread or from an I/O completion thread or whatever. When the UI thread gets around to processing that message, it invokes the continuation. Just the same as when the UI thread gets around to processing a button click, it invokes the click handler.

Comment: A minor nit: In your example, the code is actually not running most of the time. It should be spending most of its time asleep waiting for messages to arrive. However, when messages do arrive, things are exactly as you say.